# ¿Cómo crear múltiples columnas con R en una posición concreta?

Tags: r

Tengo una tabla en R con 10 columnas en las que hay diferentes palabras. Estoy intentando crear diez columnas nuevas que aparezcan antes de las que ya tengo y que me indiquen el número de palabra.

Por ejemplo, la primera columna se llamaría "número de palabra" y pondría "palabra1" en todas las casillas de la columna (esta columna nueva, además, aparecería antes de la columna que contiene las palabras de la lista 1). A continuación, aparecería la columna 2 llamada "número de palabra" otra vez y pondría "palabra2" en toda la columna (esta nueva columna aparecería justo antes de la segunda lista de palabras).

Por el momento, solo he podido crear columnas de manera individual, pero tendría que repetir el proceso 10 veces (una vez por columna). Abajo está el código que he usado:

`add.column(data.frame, número_de_palabra = "palabra1", .after = 2)`

¿Habría alguna manera de condensar la creación de 10 columnas en una sola línea de código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero armemos un ejemplo de un `data.frame` con 10 columnas:

```
df <-data.frame(matrix(sample(LETTERS,120,replace = TRUE), ncol=10))
df

   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1   O  U  Y  Z  E  H  Z  Y  E   X
2   V  B  K  W  M  G  E  I  W   D
3   N  C  Q  M  L  W  K  B  L   M
4   T  Y  L  P  K  H  M  R  T   W
5   G  R  X  I  Y  R  T  U  T   G
6   Q  Y  C  M  N  U  O  I  Z   X
7   I  Q  R  Q  I  N  E  Q  D   C
8   V  H  H  V  S  T  Z  U  L   S
9   B  P  R  R  J  B  B  J  W   C
10  Q  K  B  Y  Y  P  W  F  K   N
11  R  N  H  T  S  J  T  Y  L   L
12  Q  C  D  L  D  R  S  Y  V   N
```

Tu requerimiento es "intercalar" 10 nuevas columnas entre las columnas existentes con el texto `Palabra<N>`. Una forma de hacerlo es la siguiente:

```
df <- cbind(df, 
            matrix(rep(paste0("Palabra",1:dim(df)[2]), dim(df)[1]), ncol=10, byrow = T)
            )

df <- df[,c(rbind(1:10,11:20))]
df

   X1        1 X2        2 X3        3 X4        4 X5        5 X6        6 X7        7 X8        8 X9        9 X10        10
1   A Palabra1  O Palabra2  N Palabra3  Y Palabra4  C Palabra5  S Palabra6  U Palabra7  M Palabra8  H Palabra9   A Palabra10
2   N Palabra1  W Palabra2  I Palabra3  V Palabra4  A Palabra5  R Palabra6  Y Palabra7  F Palabra8  E Palabra9   N Palabra10
3   B Palabra1  N Palabra2  S Palabra3  R Palabra4  A Palabra5  V Palabra6  R Palabra7  J Palabra8  R Palabra9   O Palabra10
4   M Palabra1  Y Palabra2  U Palabra3  G Palabra4  Y Palabra5  G Palabra6  S Palabra7  W Palabra8  W Palabra9   X Palabra10
5   Z Palabra1  P Palabra2  L Palabra3  B Palabra4  M Palabra5  S Palabra6  E Palabra7  K Palabra8  U Palabra9   N Palabra10
6   W Palabra1  W Palabra2  G Palabra3  O Palabra4  G Palabra5  P Palabra6  E Palabra7  Q Palabra8  V Palabra9   Y Palabra10
7   L Palabra1  T Palabra2  P Palabra3  L Palabra4  T Palabra5  P Palabra6  Q Palabra7  E Palabra8  I Palabra9   K Palabra10
8   J Palabra1  S Palabra2  P Palabra3  O Palabra4  V Palabra5  L Palabra6  O Palabra7  S Palabra8  A Palabra9   S Palabra10
9   X Palabra1  U Palabra2  V Palabra3  S Palabra4  G Palabra5  B Palabra6  M Palabra7  X Palabra8  J Palabra9   D Palabra10
10  T Palabra1  Z Palabra2  U Palabra3  L Palabra4  U Palabra5  F Palabra6  M Palabra7  E Palabra8  Q Palabra9   I Palabra10
11  Y Palabra1  A Palabra2  L Palabra3  O Palabra4  Q Palabra5  H Palabra6  X Palabra7  O Palabra8  M Palabra9   W Palabra10
12  N Palabra1  A Palabra2  L Palabra3  I Palabra4  B Palabra5  J Palabra6  J Palabra7  Z Palabra8  S Palabra9   Y Palabra10
```

**Explicación:**

- Con `matrix(rep(paste0("Palabra",1:dim(df)[2]), dim(df)[1]), ncol=10, byrow = T)`generamos una matriz de 10 columnas, dónde cada columna tiene el texto `Palabra<N>` en toda la misma.
- Combinamos la matriz con el `data.frame` mediante `cbind()` eso nos dejará las nueva columnas al final del `data.frame`.
- Por último con `df[,c(rbind(1:10,11:20))]` reordenamos las columnas intercalándolas como estás buscando.